# Having difficulty to get SSH with a Yubikey working with macOS monterey

Tags: yubico, yubikey

I'm following the FIDO U2F instructions on https://developers.yubico.com/SSH/ on macOS Monterey with openSSH 8.6 and run into the following issue:

```
~ ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk -f ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
Generating public/private ecdsa-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
Key enrollment failed: unknown or unsupported key type
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: I was only able to get it working on OpenSSH from Homebrew (OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1). OpenSSH from Apple (OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3) may not be compiled with the yubikey options.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use Homebrew's OpenSSH

```sh
$ brew install openssh
```

Once installed, you have to override the one in your PATH by putting the openssh folder at the beginning of your `PATH` in your `rc` file like this

```
$ export PATH=$(brew --prefix openssh)/bin:$PATH
```

Once you've done that and you've `source`d your `rc` file you should be able to generate your key

Tested on macOS Monterey and `OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l`

Comment: I'm baffled why Apple would do this. Do you know if it's something expected to always stay like this, or do they usually fix such (IMO) bugs?

Comment: It's not a bug, it just uses a different ssh version that doesn't support YubiKeys

Comment: OpenSSH version 8.2p1 supports it, but Apple is specifically disables it with a `--disable-security-key` compile flag.  https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/OpenSSH/pull/1